# Get shape by Id or Name

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is there any way to get a shape if you know its `Id`?

For example:

```
Dim myshape As Shape
myshape.Id = 42
myshape = getShapeById(myshape.Id)
```

Or, alternatively, could I get the shape by `Name`?

```
Dim myshape As Shape
myshape.Name = "Rectangle 42"
myshape = getShapeByName(myshape.Name)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a `Shape` by `Name`, you do...:

```
Function getShapeByName(shapeName As String, Slide As Integer)
    Set getShapeByName = ActivePresentation.Slides(Slide).Shapes(shapeName)
End Function

Dim myshape As Shape
myshape = getShapeByName("Rectangle 42", 1)
```

Comment: I thought I already answered this @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465465/get-shape-id-by-name and now you wanted the opposite (Get Shape by `.Id`) as in my post.

Comment: @Otaku Yeah, but I didn't really understand the code entirely until now. :)

Comment: What if the object does not exist? How would I check before accessing something in vba?

Comment: @paskl Do you mean if the name does not exist? Something like this, perhaps: http://pastebin.com/1Fk8WQCB

Answer (score 5):

Getting a shape `.Name` by its `.Id` is somewhat more convoluted than [getting its `.Id` by its `.Name`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465465/get-shape-id-by-name).

But here's how it's done:

```
Sub PrintShapeName()
    Debug.Print getNameByID(3, 1)
End Sub

Function getNameByID(shapeID As Long, slide As Integer)
    Dim ap As Presentation: Set ap = ActivePresentation
    Dim sl As slide: Set sl = ap.Slides(slide)
    sl.Shapes.SelectAll
    Dim sr As ShapeRange
    Set sr = Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange
    Dim s As Shape
    For Each s In sr
        If s.id = shapeID Then
            getNameByID = s.Name
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sName = ActivePresentation.Slides(k).Shapes(j).Name
```

where `k` is the slide number and `j` and the shape number on that slide.

You can loop through each pages shapes with something like:

```
k = 1
For j = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides(k).Shapes.Count
Next j
```

Chris

Comment: Question is about Shape.Id not Shape number, because Shape.ID is the only field which identifies a shape uniquely in a slide