# How to find the index number of a named shape in vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I ran the following code

```
for i=1 to activedocument.Shapes.count : debug.Print activedocument.shapes(i).name : next
```

And got a list of shapes, however a shape was missing

I selected a shape not included, and got the name with `debug.print selection.Shaperange.name`

How can I do something similar to find its index, and find out what is going on here?

EDIT:  The following code finds me all my shapes

```
Dim i
Dim rngStory As Word.Range

For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    For Each i In rngStory.ShapeRange
        Debug.Print rngStory.StoryType & ": " & i.name
    Next
Next
```

The problem was that activedocument.shapes only returns shapes in the main story.  The above code cycles through all the ranges, and so finds all the shapes.

However, this still doesn't answer the central question of how to get a shape index.

Comment: Try `i=0 to`... Just a hunch. Anyway, usually there is a `.index` property, but I don't know about shapes.

Comment: can you try `For Each` loop instead of `For`? sounds a bit like a shape that contains multiple shapes. Also, Record Macro of selecting the Shape to check the generated code.

Comment: my first though too, but nope i=0 doesn't exist.  Tested .count +1 too just in case something funny was happening there

Comment: `for each shape in activedocument.shapes :debug.Print shape.name : next` gives same result

Comment: does `activedocument.shapes("shapename").name` return anything?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav "shapename"

Comment: I think it's because you are using a shape range, rather than the shapes collecton?  could the shape missing be excluded from the range?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav re-read the question, unless I'm misunderstanding what you've just said, it doesn't really make any sense.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me. Specify the worksheet name and name of the control

Word:

```
Public Function GetShapeIndex(ByVal strName As String) As Long

    GetShapeIndex = ActiveDocument.Shapes(strName).ID

End Function
```

Excel:

```
Public Function GetShapeIndex(ByVal strWorksheet As String, ByVal strName As String) As Long

    GetShapeIndex = Worksheets(strWorksheet).Shapes(strName).ID

End Function
```

Comment: I'm in MS-Word.  Leave this up though, in case someone needs this in Excel in the future

Comment: Edited to include a Word version

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to work, since `Shape.ID` is not to be confused with the `Index`. `.ID` is not updated if you add/delete other shapes. The index of the `.Shapes`-collection is. (Test this: add 3 shapes. Debug.print their `.ID`. Delete the 2nd one, and then try to access your 3rd shape with it's ID and `ThisDocument.Shapes(i)`. It won't work.). With `.Shapes` being a collection, there is no separate list of the `Index`s / indices included. Here's a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527073/get-shape-by-id-or-name

Comment: @MartinDreher very deceptive, I thought this was the solution for a second

Comment: Hey people, no need to downvote... Someone took the time out of their day to solve the problem, doesn't warrant a downvote for not getting the correct solution through a pretty valiant attempt

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to loop to get the id. However, I gather this didn't work for you the first time, since your selected shape wasn't in the `Shapes`-collection (weird). Try assigning `Selection.Parent` to an object variable and inspect the type it gets in your VBA-editor... maybe this gives a lead.

Comment: @MartinDreher see question update.  Shapes collection seems to refer only to wdDefaultStory, even though it's a property of the document not the story.  I'm getting deja vu, I'm sure this is true for a bunch of stuff and I've encountered this before.  To get all shapes, you have to loop through all stories.  Still not sure how to get the index though; I can't believe the only way to get an index from a name/ID is to loop through all indices and pick out the one that matches the name. I mean I guess you could dump them into a 2d array, and pull out the index against the string but... eugh