# Find the index number of a builtin/userdefined style without creating a lookup/hash table

Tags: vba, ms-word

The VBA Word listing below allows me to dump the contents of my user-defined style "Appendix 9". There are 1-9 levels that are based off of the Header 1-9 builtin style.

Although I can get the info knowing the name of my  user-defined style or guessing at an index number (even though its the first in the sorted alphabetic list), there is no object method to return the index number assigned based on passing the starting level 1 user-defined name "Appendix 1" to it. Then I can cycle through a loop from this returned index number to level 9 while performing various "find/replace" processing on info related to this user-defined style list.

The only way I can think of, is to read-in all the current styles within the ActiveDocument visible/not visible and build a list of all the style names against the assigned index number. Then
lookup/hash this table of styles to find the level 1 index number for the user-defined style I would like to do find/replace processing on and use the .item(index) method.

The same thing is an issue with the fontlist too not being able to get the index number assigned to a user-defined font via a method without having to create a lookup/hash table.

Also by being able to retrieve the starting index number for each of my user-defined styles it will be a short list and stored in an array.  Thus the code listed below which dumps style information given a user-defined style name with the code repeated for each of my user-defined styles can be generalized to a function/subroutine with only one copy of the code and each of the starting index numbers can be plugged into into this common code. The starting index number can be plugged into a for loop to cycle thru all 9 levels to dump the user-defined style info.

Any easier way?

```
Debug.Print "//==========================================="
        Debug.Print "Base style= " _
        & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").Basestyle & vbCr _
        & "Style name= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").NameLocal & vbCr _
        & "Style name(index=1)= " & ActiveDocument.Styles(index:=1).NameLocal & vbCr _
        & "Style name(index=2)= " & ActiveDocument.Styles(index:=2).NameLocal & vbCr _
        & "Style name(index=3)= " & ActiveDocument.Styles(index:=3).NameLocal & vbCr _
        & "Style name(index=11)= " & ActiveDocument.Styles(index:=11).NameLocal & vbCr _
        & "Style Linked= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").Linked & vbCr _
        & "Style LinkedStyle= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").LinkStyle & vbCr _
        & "Next para style= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").NextParagraphStyle & vbCr _
        & "Style Parent= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").Parent & vbCr _
        & "Style Type= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").Type & vbCr _
        & "Style Visibility= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").Visibility & vbCr _
        & "Style ListLevel= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").ListLevelNumber & vbCr _
        & "Style InUse= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").InUse & vbCr _
        & "Style AutomaticallyUpdate= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").AutomaticallyUpdate & vbCr _
        & "Style BuiltIn= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").BuiltIn & vbCr _
        & "Style Quick= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").QuickStyle & vbCr _
        & "Style UnHideWhenUsed= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").UnhideWhenUsed & vbCr _
        & "Style Font Name= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").Font.Name & vbCr _
        & "Style Font Size= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").Font.Size & vbCr _
        & "Style Font Bold= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").Font.Bold & vbCr _
        & "Style Font TextColor= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").Font.TextColor & vbCr _
        & "Style Font Italic= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").Font.Italic & vbCr _
        & "Style Para Format Style Align = " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").ParagraphFormat.Alignment & vbCr
        
        ' & "Style Shading= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").Shading & vbCr
        ' & "Style Table= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").Table & vbCr _
        ' & "Style ListTemplate= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").ListTemplate & vbCr
        ' & "Style Linked ListTemplate= " & ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 9").LinkToListTemplate & vbCr _
```

Comment: Not sure whether you're after the list level, or the VBA constant for the base style. For the latter, see: https://www.thedoctools.com/word-macros-tips/word-tips/word-style-names-in-english-danish-german-french/

Comment: Here is what I can do with VBA for my level 1 user-defined style Appendix 1. Two ways to do it.
x=ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 1").NameLocal
x=ActiveDocument.Styles(index:=1).NameLocal
I want to get the index number so that I don't have to do the above steps. Lets assume I can do this.  Styleindex= ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix 1")
Then use it in  for loop style_n  from styleIndex to styleindex+9
    set the find   .style= styles(style_n).item
    do other stuff
end loop 
Thus a common for loop for processing all my user-defined styles at all levels.

Answer (score 0):

When the functionality you want doesn't exist you find a workaround, e.g.

```
   Dim index As Long
   For index = 1 To 9
      .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Appendix " & index)
   Next index
```

Comment: I kinda thought that probably was no way to get the index no using the object and methods on the style type. I thought I missed something in my searches that is why I was heading in the direction of building a lookup table that contained the first level of each of my style types. Then any use of them would lookup the first entry and loop 1-9 on this starting index number.  Thus one for-loop used in a fcn for all of them.  The other way is to duplicate the for loop for each style type like you suggested in your comment.

Comment: Thus, it would be useful for Microsoft to add a method to return the index # to the object model. I'd think methods should be available to go both ways: 1) specify style type get index, 2) specify index get style type. The same applies to fonts and other similar stuff.

Comment: @MSW - that will never happen.

Comment: It seems that howto find the index is a common question on various things such as shapes, tables and other things. ie https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761117/how-to-find-the-index-number-of-a-named-shape-in-vba?rq=1 
What I'm trying to do is segregate searching of a document based on built-in/user-defined style and replace a word if found with the bolded version of it. It can be in headings, paragraphs, text based on user-defined style. (see earlier posted/answered ? on SO). This allows me to turn on/off searches based on style type to debug or as needed.

Comment: Ive been playing around with VBA code to segregate the builtin vs user-defined styles that dump a listing of them in alphabetic order and numbering (index#) them. If a new template is added to add/remove style types, the code won't need to know to much about them by having to hardcode them in and deleting them from the code when not imported. The generated list will take care of this. All I need to do is set a flag to turn on/off which ones in the list should be used in the style and word search to do find/replace to make text bold. Thus the need for index #.