# Get category names of waterfall chart

Tags: vba, vsto, office-interop, powerpoint

I am trying to read the category names of a waterfall chart in a PowerPoint VSTO project.
So far, I was unable to do so.

Here is what I tried:

- `chart.SeriesCollection(x).Axes(y).CategoryNames` - not available for this chart type
- `chart.SeriesCollection(x).XValues` - not available for this chart type
- `chart.SeriesCollection(x).Points(y).DataLabel.Text` / `.Caption` - this returns the point value, not the category name, e.g. -130
- `chart.SeriesCollection(x).DataLabels(y).Text` / `.Caption` - same as previous: It returns the point values

Then, I tried reading the source data directly via `chart.ChartData.Workbook` but this is also not available.

So, how can I read the category names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that, as of this writing, the [XlChartType enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Microsoft.Office.Core.XlChartType);k(VST.ProjectItem.Addin);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) is missing a member for Waterfall. (Waterfall has a `ChartType` integer value of 119, which is simply missing in the enumeration.)

As the missing enumeration creates all sorts of issues, I decided to write code that would convert the chart to an enumerated type, place the Category Names into an array, and then use PowerPoint's `Undo` functionality to restore the chart.

```
PowerPoint.Chart myChart = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides[1].Shapes[2].Chart;
myChart.ChartType = Office.XlChartType.xlBarStacked;
PowerPoint.Axis CategoryAxis = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides[1].Shapes[2].Chart.Axes(PowerPoint.XlAxisType.xlCategory, PowerPoint.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
Array CatNames = (Array)((object)CategoryAxis.CategoryNames);
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("Undo");
//Do something here with the CatNames array
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach, but wouldn't this change the visual representation of the chart for a short time?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth yes, that could happen (especially if the PC running the code is an older vintage). There is no native way in PowerPoint's object model to turn off screen updating, but I imagine this code could be converted to C#: [PowerPoint VBA Equivalent of Application.ScreenUpdating](http://skp.mvps.org/ppt00033.htm). You could then turn off `ScreenUpdating`, run the code to grab the Category Names, and then turn `ScreenUpdating` back on.

Comment: OK, that could work. I have an entirely different problem with this approach though: I am starting my work from the current selection, i.e. I do something like `var chart = Selection.ShapeRange(1).Chart`. After changing the chart type, not only my current `chart` object is invalid, the whole hierarchy has changed. The `ShapeRange(1).Chart` throws an exception and even `Selection.ShapeRange` throws. Only `SlideRange` works, so it seems as if the selection changed.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth it is possible the conversion of the chart is altering the `Selection` object. If possible, I would refactor to replace the use of `Selection` to identify the desired chart by looping through the `Shapes` collection in each slide using `HasChart` and/or other identifying properties. If issues still arise after `Selection` has been removed, I would try exploring other enumeration members for the conversion.

Comment: And how would I identify a chart? It doesn't have an ID or something, does it?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth shapes in PowerPoint have a [Shape.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/shape-name-property-powerpoint). They also have a [Shape.Id property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/shape-id-property-powerpoint?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) These can be used to identify a shape that contains the chart. Here is an example: [Get Shape by Id or Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527073/get-shape-by-id-or-name).

Comment: Yeah, that works. Is all of this only an issue of VSTO? Or of VBA as well? This is REALLY bad...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth PowerPoint VBA and VSTO share the same object model, so they, for the most part, share the same difficulties. IMHO, developing in VSTO is easier as the .NET libraries can be leveraged. PowerPoint VBA was released in 1997, the language is virtually unchanged since then, and the object model has received very little maintenance. Most issues remain for years or decades. For example, Office 2016 was released in September 2015, which means the Waterfall enumeration issue has gone uncorrected for almost 2.5 years. So when you write that this is REALLY bad, you are being charitable.

Comment: Thanks, that comment made my day ;)